# How to freeze the checkbox after clicking checkbox? I try it but it not working

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I try to freeze checkbox but it not working. I mention the name of the checkbox as is_top_property. Kindly help me. Here the code

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-title"><strong>{{__("Top Property")}}</strong></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="is_top_property" onclick="check();" @if($row->is_top_property) checked @endif value="1"> {{__("Enable Top Property")}}
            <script>
            public function check(){
                if($("is_top_property").is(":checked")){
                    alert("Thanks for selecting");
                    $('is_top_property').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            }
            </script>                                        
               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a class to the input like `class="is_top_property` and then add the missing `.` in `$("is_top_property")`. Because `$("is_top_property")` means that you are looking for an `<is_top_property>` element and that of course does not exist.

Comment: `public function check(){` ?? This is JavaScript, not JAVA. Remove the public

Answer (score 0):

This is how to code your example in jQuery proper:

1. Use the correct selector - here `$("[name=is_top_property]")` but you could also add a class and use `$(".is_top_property")`
2. do not use inline event handling
3. We need a timeout to check the box before alerting
4. I added code to visually disable the label too

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name=is_top_property]").on("change", function() {
    const checked = this.checked;
    if (checked) setTimeout(function() { alert("Thanks for selecting") }, 10); // give time to show the checkmark
    $(this)
      .prop('disabled', checked)
      .parent('label').toggleClass("disabled", checked)
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="is_top_property" value="1"> Enable Top Property</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check() function not required there, just need to find the check box in dom element and disable when it checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#is_top_property").click(function(){              
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
             $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        }
   });
 }
```